# How to fix Jython error on line that does not exist

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, jython, jes

so I am relatively new to coding using JES (Jython)

I wrote an 81 lines long code but when I run the program, it says your code contains at least one syntax error, meaning it is not legal Jython.
Error on line 97

So line 97 does not even exist since my entire code is just 81 lines long.

I will attach it here.
Would REALLY appreciate any help I could get because this assignment is due tomorrow.

```py
def createCollage():
  filename1 = pickAFile()
  antelope = makePicture(filename1)
  print(antelope)
  filename2 = pickAFile()
  rabbit = makePicture(filename2)
  print(rabbit)
  filename3 = pickAFile()
  gcu = makePicture(filename3)
  print(gcu)
  filename4 = pickAFile()
  omar = makePicture(filename4)
  print(omar)
  canvas = makeEmptyPicture(1450,350)
  print (canvas)  
  targetX=0
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(gcu)):
    targetY = getHeight(canvas)-getHeight(gcu)
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(gcu)):
      px=getPixel(gcu,sourceX,sourceY)
      cx=getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY)
      setColor(cx,getColor(px))
      targetY = targetY+1
    targetX = targetX+1
  show(canvas)
  targetX=60
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(antelope)):
    targetY = getHeight(canvas)-getHeight(antelope)
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(antelope)):
      px=getPxel(antelope,sourceX,sourceY)
      cx=getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY)
      setColor(cx,getColor(px))
      targetY = targetY+1
    targetX = targetX+1
  repaint(canvas)
  show(canvas)
  targetX=390
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(rabbit)):
    targetY = getHeight(canvas)-getHeight(rabbit)
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(rabbit)):
      px=getPixel(rabbit,sourceX,sourceY)
      cx=getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY)
      setColor(cx,getColor(px))
      targetY = targetY+1
    targetX = targetX+1
  repaint(canvas)
  show(canvas)
  targetX=720
  for sourceX in range(0,300)
    targetY = getHeight(canvas)-300
    for sourceY in range(0,300):
      if sourceY > 75:
        px=getPixel(antelope,sourceX,sourceY)
        cx=getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY)
        setColor(cx,getColor(px))      
        targetY = targetY+1
      else:
        px=getPixel(rabbit,sourceX,sourceY)
        cx=getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY)
        setColor(cx,getColor(px))
        targetY = targetY+1
    targetX = targetX+1
  repaint(canvas)
  show(canvas)
  targetX=1050
  for sourceX in range(0,getWidth(omar)):
    targetY = getHeight(canvas)-getHeight(omar)
    for sourceY in range(0,getHeight(omar)):
      px=getPixel(omar,sourceX,spirceY)
      cx=getPixel(canvas,targetX,targetY)
      setColor(cx,getColor(px))
      targetY = targetY+1
    targetX = targetX+1
  repaint(canvas)
  show(canvas)
  show(antelope)
  show(rabbit)
  show(gcu)
  show(omar)
  show(canvas)
  return canvas
```

Comment: screenshots are hard to read, and won't be found with google. Could you maybe paste the code as text instead, inside code tags (three backticks)? Will also make it easier for anybody trying to reproduce your issue to figure out the fix

Comment: one thing I see right now is that on line 49 you are missing a colon at the end. But if that is it, the error message is kinda useless

Comment: Does this help at all guys??